# Pass request data from UIPageViewController to child views

Tags: ios, swift, request, uipageviewcontroller, pass-data

I have `MainViewController` that is my **UIPageViewController**. Ther are 2 views `FirstDataViewController` and `SecondDataViewController` that i want to show.

I want to execute my request that updates **items** in `MainViewControllre` and then pass it to my 2 child views.

`getData` is my function that contains data from **Request** and then updates `MainViewController's` items

```
extension MainViewController {
    func getData() {
        getBasicData() { [weak self] (basicModel) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            strongSelf.getExperienceData() { [weak self] (experienceModel) in
                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

                let items = RequestItems(basicData: basicModel,
                                         experienceData: experienceModel)

                strongSelf.updateItems(items: items)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewController:

```
class MainViewController: UIPageViewController {

    var items: RequestItems

    let firstDataViewController: FirstDataViewController
    let secondDataViewController: SecondDataViewController

    let basicDataManager: APIManagerProtocol
    let experienceDataManager: APIManagerProtocol

    private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
        return [self.firstDataViewController, self.secondDataViewController]
    }()

    convenience init() {
        self.init(with: RequestItems())
    }

    init(with items: RequestItems) {

        self.items = items

        let apiManager = APIManager()
        basicDataManager = apiManager.createBasicDataManager()
        experienceDataManager = apiManager.createExperienceDataManager()

        self.firstDataViewController = FirstDataViewController(with: items)
        self.secondDataViewController = SecondDataViewController(with: items)

        super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)

        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
    }

    func updateItems(items: RequestItems) {
        self.items = items
    }
}
```

How to use `getData()` function to update MainViewController items first and then pass data to child views? Or maybe there is just better option to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good solution. "GetData" method needs some time to execute completely so you should:

- Execute "getData" before load MainViewController, then pass "request items" to it and update yours views.

But I assume that your MainViewController is first controller in your application so you should:

1. Add completion block to your "getData" method:

   ```
   func getData(_ completion: [RequestItems] -> ()) {

       getBasicData() { [weak self] (basicModel) in

           guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

           strongSelf.getExperienceData() { [weak self] (experienceModel) in

               guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

               let items = RequestItems(basicData: basicModel,
                                    experienceData: experienceModel)

               completion(items)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add "updateItems" method to yours view controllers (instead of passing it in init method)
3. Call your "getData" method with completion handler but outside of MainViewController init

   ```
   init(with items: RequestItems) {
       ...
       self.items = items

       self.firstDataViewController = FirstDataViewController()
       self.secondDataViewController = SecondDataViewController()
       ...
   }

   func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       getBasicData { [weak self] (items) in 
           guard let strongSelf = self else { return }


           strongSelf.updateItems(items)
           strongSelf.firstDataViewController.updateItems(with: items)
           strongSelf.secondDataViewController.updateItems(with: items)
       }
   }

   func updateItems(items: RequestItems) {
       self.items = items
   }
   ```

Comment: The problem is that `updateItems` is executed after init of `child ViewControllers`. I cannot pass the data and then use it in `viewDidLoad` in one of the `child ViewController`.

Comment: What's the logic behind "init" of those view controllers? Why you want to put this logic into "init" so badly?

Comment: I do not want it but it seems like getData is updating childViewController too late and i cannot use data in there. I am probably updating it in a wrong way.

This is my MainViewController which is first view controller in my app.
1.) https://pastebin.com/mvwmvQkT
2.) Extension: https://pastebin.com/chv4enQ8

And this is one of child ViewController.
2.) https://pastebin.com/CEdyL7kL